# Getting ora-00907 missing right parenthesis error when creating table. New to databse, don't know what's going on

Tags: database, oracle

I just started taking a database class and I'm getting an error I don't know how to identify what is wrong. I get the ORA-00907 missing right parenthesis error, although I don't think I missed any parenthesis.

Here is the code:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_USER_LAB
2  (   SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID int PRIMARY KEY
3  ,   SYSTEM_USER_NAME string NOT NULL
4  ,   SYSTEM_USER_GROUP_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
   COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_ID)
5  ,   SYSTEM_USER_TYPE int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
   COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB_ID)
6  ,   FIRST_NAME string
7  ,   MIDDLE_NAME string
8  ,   LAST_NAME string
9  ,   CREATED_BY int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
   SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
10  ,   CREATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL
11  ,   LAST_UPDATED_BY int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
   SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
12  ,   LAST_UPDATE_DATE DATE NOT NULL);
,   SYSTEM_USER_GROUP_ID int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES 
   COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_ID)
                         *
ERROR at line 4:
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Answer (score 1):

Quite a few issues, such as

- `string` is invalid datatype in Oracle
- you are referencing `COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB`, two of its columns (from `system_user_group_id` and `system_user_type`) - is that correct? I created it just to make `CREATE SYSTEM_USER_LAB` work, creating one primary and one unique key
- foreign key constraints look suspicious

Here's my suggestion - see how it works, adjust it if necessary.

```
SQL> create table common_lookup_lab (common_lookup_id int primary key,
  2                                  common_lookup_lab_id int unique);

Table created.

SQL> create table system_user_lab
  2    (system_user_lab_id   int  constraint pk_sul primary key,
  3     system_user_name     varchar2(30) not null,
  4     system_user_group_id int constraint fk_sul_cll1
  5                              references common_lookup_lab (common_lookup_id),
  6     system_user_type     int constraint fk_sul_cll2
  7                              references common_lookup_lab (common_lookup_lab_id),
  8     first_name           varchar2(20),
  9     middle_name          varchar2(20),
 10     last_name            varchar2(20),
 11     created_by           int constraint fk_sul_sul1
 12                              references system_user_lab (system_user_lab_id),
 13     creation_date        date not null,
 14     last_updated_by      int constraint fk_sul_sul2
 15                              references system_user_lab (system_user_lab_id),
 16     last_update_date     date not null
 17    );

Table created.
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing up [the syntax for inline and out-of-line constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/constraint.html#GUID-1055EA97-BA6F-4764-A15F-1024FD5B6DFE).

You can either remove the `FOREIGN KEY` part of the inline constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_USER_LAB
(   SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID int PRIMARY KEY
,   SYSTEM_USER_NAME varchar2(10) NOT NULL
,   SYSTEM_USER_GROUP_ID int REFERENCES COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_ID)
,   SYSTEM_USER_TYPE int REFERENCES COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB_ID)
,   FIRST_NAME varchar2(10)
,   MIDDLE_NAME varchar2(10)
,   LAST_NAME varchar2(10)
,   CREATED_BY int REFERENCES SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
,   CREATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL
,   LAST_UPDATED_BY int REFERENCES SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
,   LAST_UPDATE_DATE DATE NOT NULL);
```

or switch to out-of-line constraints:

```
CREATE TABLE SYSTEM_USER_LAB
(   SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID int PRIMARY KEY
,   SYSTEM_USER_NAME varchar2(10) NOT NULL
,   SYSTEM_USER_GROUP_ID int
,   SYSTEM_USER_TYPE int
,   FIRST_NAME varchar2(10)
,   MIDDLE_NAME varchar2(10)
,   LAST_NAME varchar2(10)
,   CREATED_BY int
,   CREATION_DATE DATE NOT NULL
,   LAST_UPDATED_BY int
,   LAST_UPDATE_DATE DATE NOT NULL
,   CONSTRAINT FK_1 FOREIGN KEY (SYSTEM_USER_GROUP_ID)
      REFERENCES COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_ID)
,   CONSTRAINT FK_2 FOREIGN KEY (SYSTEM_USER_TYPE)
      REFERENCES COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB(COMMON_LOOKUP_LAB_ID)
,   CONSTRAINT FK_3 FOREIGN KEY (CREATED_BY)
      REFERENCES SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
,   CONSTRAINT FK_4 FOREIGN KEY (LAST_UPDATED_BY)
      REFERENCES SYSTEM_USER_LAB(SYSTEM_USER_LAB_ID)
);
```

Obviously pick better names for those constraints than I have, and for both versions, make sure they are referencing the right things in the parent table(s).

I've also changed `string` to `varchar2(10)`, as the former is not [a valid data type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html). Again, make sure those are actually sensible sizes, I picked `10` at random. And `int` is not a built-in data type, but it is [a supported ANSI SQL type](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Data-Types.html), so that's OK but perhaps slightly unusual.